# AD623 ANZ vs. BNZ?

Tags: packages, instrumentation-amplifier

I have simulated my first circuit ever and now I wanted to order an Analog AD623 to actually build it. I gathered that I need the 8-DIP package to stick the IC on the breadboard, but there are actually two versions:

http://www.digikey.ch/product-detail/en/AD623ANZ/AD623ANZ-ND/750974 $3.79
http://www.digikey.ch/product-detail/en/AD623BNZ/AD623BNZ-ND/760282 $5.25

I fail to find any differences between the ANZ and BNZ version besides the price. Can you tell me what this stuff is about?

Comment: If you read the Analog-Devices inc datasheet linked on the Digikey pages, you'll see it has separate columns for AD623A and AD623B which list the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suffix ANZ or BRZ have a meaning.  have a look at p.23 in the [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD623.pdf) (rev.D).

A or B - grade
N - package
Z- RoHS compliance

The ICs have manufacturing variations.  ICs are tested during production.  Some of them are rejected.  The ones that pass, are sorted into grades (or bins), depending on the variations in each individual IC.

You can see the difference between the grades on pp.3-5 in the [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD623.pdf).  AD623A and AD623B have separate columns.  Notice that grade B has somewhat better characteristics.

[image]

Comment: Ok great thanks, should have looked at the data sheet more closely.